# A problem in determining conditions for relational matrix for module to be cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

I have met this question in my Abstract Algebra class dealing with modules, it is a problem I do not really understand how to do, which states:

> Let $ F $ be a field with characteristic 3 and we define the ring of polynomials in x $ R = F[x] $. Now for any a,b in the field F we define an R module $ M(a,b) $ as follows:
>   the ordered set of generators of M(a,b) is $ S = \{ m_1,m_2,m_3 \} $ with the relations matrix $ A(a,b) $ with respect to S as follows:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     x+2       & 5 & x-a &  \\
>     1      & x-2 & x-b &  \\
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> We are to find a necessary and sufficient condition on a and b such that the module $ M(a,b) $ is cyclic and we are to find a generator for it in such a case.

My problem here is I know not what relations matrix means in this context, so I am asking for an explanation of this topic and how to deal with it, I do not even know why the matrix is of dimensions 2x3 so it is all a blur to me. I appreciate the help here thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "relations matrix" just means that $M(a,b)$ is generated by $S$ with the relations $(x+2)m_1+5m_2+(x-a)m_3=0$ and $m_1+(x-2)m_2+(x-b)m_3=0$.  That is, when you take the relations matrix and multiply it by the column vector $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$, you get $0$.

Comment: Thanks for this now I understand but how would I get cyclicity?